# Vite + React not bundling correctly in dev mode

Tags: reactjs, vite

I've been migrating my project from CRA template to Vite, so now i'm on step, when i have setted up all configuration, but when i start application with `npm run vite`, that's what i get in browser:

[app in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/285wa.png)

It looks like application isn't bundled correctly with chunks, and it requesting all js modules, that used on page, so i see only blank screen and infinite loading.

There are config files:

[vite.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGTbD.png)

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBYuT.png)

[tsconfig.node.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4rh1.png)

I have removed all CRA and Webpack files, also after a long time waiting and page refreshing the page loads. Is there a way to fix that problem? And why is it happening?

Comment: Vite doesn't bundle the code in dev mode.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.